# What does "host" mean in this MDN reference article about globalThis?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser

I was reading about `globalThis` in the MDN documentation, specifically here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis

In the **Description** section, the first note says:

> globalThis is generally the same concept as the global object (i.e. adding properties to globalThis makes them global variables) — this is the case for browsers and Node — but hosts are allowed to provide a different value for globalThis that's unrelated to the global object.

I just want a clarification from native english speakers and programmers that are expert in JS about the meaning of "hosts" in this context, because I'm not getting it.

I don't think the [host](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Host) definition from the MDN glossary applies here - it seems way too broad to me and does not help me understand when could I find globalThis changed in its nature.

There is not much that I could try, since it is a matter of text comprehension.

Comment: Host is the same thing as server or computer.

Comment: @Barmar yes, but that's not what is meant here

Comment: The glossary entry is for the `Host:` HTTP request header, nothing to do with JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, "host" refers to the application that is *hosting* (or: embedding) the ECMAScript engine and providing the runtime.

Another usage example from MDN is this paragraph from [JavaScript technologies overview](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/JavaScript_technologies_overview#javascript_implementations):

> JavaScript engines expose a public API which application developers can use to integrate JavaScript into their software. By far, the most common host environment for JavaScript is web browsers. Web browsers typically use the public API to create host objects responsible for reflecting the DOM into JavaScript.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, so it's "any other platform where the ECMAScript code could run", right? Like Hermes, for instance?

Comment: @MatteoSmaila I would classify hermes as a js engine, not as a host application (which would be the whole android app).

Comment: I was feeling dumb while commenting, but turns out I didn't get it right, so I'm glad I asked for the clarification. Very helpful, thank you!

Comment: @MatteoSmaila On the other hand, hermes also is the name of the framework used to generate android apps iiuc, so the distinction isn't as clear. There's a bit of ambiguity if a js engine is purpose-built for a single project.

Comment: Yes, but I understood your point nevertheless: the application is not strictly the engine, in general - the engine is just a part of it. Any application that embeds an ECMAScript engine (or, for that matter, implements a crappy engine itself, even in a monolithic fashion) is called a host and is allowed to expose a globalThis different from what you'd expect in a standard browser, or in Node.JS (which are prominent hosts themselves).

Comment: …although then again the spec does not care *who* made the decision to use a custom `globalThis`. And of course it depends on the engine implementation how a host can customise this, or whether they can customise it at all. Of course ultimately it's the host application (programmer) who decides this, however if they want to choose a particular engine they may not be given a choice :-)